# texturing bug in blender - cant paint anything directly on the mesh

Tags: mesh, texturing, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

so i was working on this project but the texture paint ain't working at all for some reason i can sculpt and do everything in the image editors and paint there as well but theres a lot of weird things going on with the project i don't know how to fix it what to do now [image] maybe check the video here as well if that helps.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOJWO.jpg

Comment: but this used to work though... i mean still does on other project files

Comment: @Chris okay it seems like its working but its not really working i mean its not textures , if i understand correctly its just assigning color values to the faces so if its not a high poly model it wont have enough granularity which is the case for me

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/LDLHCZh) this is how its supposed to work and i am using 3.1 alpha , same shit is happening on 3.0 release

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file (upload and copy paste the URL): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots couldnt upload it on the on the pasteall site but i uploaded it to google drive [Drive Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l4RdSD-l4lq1fUEoyjdWT1YuxZ6wizOr/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your normals are inverted, go in *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>

Comment: thanks dude and now i feel kinda dumb for not looking at , but thank you so much dude

Comment: Don't worry about it . classic issue